How to troubleshoot DNS
I am trying to write a simple program in C to connect to a Hostname over TCP/IP, but am struggling to get DNS working at all on Ubuntu.
I actually got this working pretty well on Windows. On Windows Server 2022 with IP 192.168.1.189, I set up a simple DNS Server to point my hostname TESTHOSTNAME towards my IP 192.168.1.157. On a Windows 10 PC I point my DNS to 192.168.1.189, then use Putty to form a Raw connection to TESTHOSTNAME. The data sent from Putty is received on TESTHOSTNAME without issue.
I cannot get this to work on Ubuntu. I point my DNS to 192.168.1.189 and verify I can ping it. But when I run "nc TESTHOSTNAME 10000" it fails with: nc: getaddrinfo for host "TESTHOSTNAME" port 10000: Name or service not known
Firewalls are off on the Ubuntu client, the Windows Server DNS machine, and the TESTHOSTNAME PC.
I see absolutely no useful logs showing either success or failures on the Windows Server Event Viewer. I enabled Debug Logging on the Windows Server DNS Server and do get this failure:
9/27/2024 12:42:48 PM 017C PACKET  00000252C1073130 UDP Snd 192.168.1.168   93c7 R Q [8281   DR SERVFAIL] A      (7)TESTHOSTNAME(0)
UDP response info at 00000252C1073130
  Socket = 936
  Remote addr 192.168.1.168, port 50201
  Time Query=13247, Queued=0, Expire=0
  Buf length = 0x0fa0 (4000)
  Msg length = 0x0019 (25)
  Message:
    XID       0x93c7
    Flags     0x8182
      QR        1 (RESPONSE)
      OPCODE    0 (QUERY)
      AA        0
      TC        0
      RD        1
      RA        1
      Z         0
      CD        0
      AD        0
      RCODE     2 (SERVFAIL)
    QCOUNT    1
    ACOUNT    0
    NSCOUNT   0
    ARCOUNT   0
    QUESTION SECTION:
    Offset = 0x000c, RR count = 0
    Name = (7)TESTHOSTNAME(0)
      QTYPE   A (1)
      QCLASS  1

I am new to DNS and am struggling to troubleshoot something mostly just seems designed to "just work":

Is there anything about the error log that might help? Are there any other logs or diagnostics I can try?

I am becoming increasingly concerned that I am not going to be able to configure a Windows DNS server to work with a Linux client (at least at my level of experience).
Is there a very simple Ubuntu DNS server I might setup instead?


Edit: Picture of the DNS Server:

Edit 2: nslookup and ping attempts:
On both Windows and Ubuntu:
Server:     192.168.1.189
Address:    192.168.1.189#53

Name:   TESTHOSTNAME.yourdomain.local
Address: 192.168.1.157

On Ubuntu a ping of both testhostname and testhostname.yourdomain.local fails, but on Windows it succeeds.
Edit 3: Video of a fresh Ubuntu install showing good nslookup but still just not able resolve it somehow:
https://youtu.be/IQTwdfAAWJ0

Are you specifying the FQDN each time, or just the host part of the name? If you're specifying just the host part of the name, you need to pay attention to how you've configured your "search domains" on your client.

Also, when you say that on Ubuntu, you "point" your DNS to 192.168.1.189, can you be more specific as to how exactly you're doing that? Are you editing /etc/resolv.conf or what? If you, say, just changed a field in a network configuration GUI somewhere, it might be helpful to double check what ended up in /etc/resolv.conf.

@Spiff I configure it through the Network settings GUI. /etc/resolv.conf is very empty, with only comments and these 3 lines:
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
Everything including the file itself is telling me not to edit it, but I support I could go for broke and try it anyway. What would I add?

What domain (zone) did you configure in the Windows DNS server? Your query doesn't have one, but I have to assume you did create some DNS zone in which you added the "TESTHOSTNAME", as otherwise I'm not sure where you'd even add a hostname in the Windows DNS server management. Can you show a screenshot of the DNS server manager, or something?

@grawity_u1686 Sure, I added one called yourdomain.local in Forward Lookup Zones, edited to show picture

@Koops128 Please note that IANA has reserved .local for mDNS, so it may get treated differently by modern OSes that support mDNS/ZeroConf, so it should be avoided for unicast DNS. Use .test or .home.arpa instead, as those are the domains IANA has reserved for private unregistered use.

@Spiff Amongst other things (I tried TESTHOSTNAME.test pretty early on) that was one the primary issues thanks. Would be nice if Windows Server didn't suggest .local as the default.

Your DNS client is asking the wrong questions, and therefore the DNS server has no answer. Take a step backwards a moment and use some of the DNS tools to identify the issue
First let's confirm the scenario

Windows Server 2022 with IP 192.168.1.189 running DNS service
Local domain is "yourdomain.local"
There is an Ubuntu DNS client machine on subnet 192.168.1.0/24
There is a Windows DNS client machine on subnet 192.168.1.0/24
In DNS you have hostname TESTHOSTNAME = IP 192.168.1.157

Using both the Windows and Ubuntu systems, use this command to ensure you have a valid DNS result on each:
nslookup testhostname.yourdomain.local 192.168.1.189

This should return you an address 192.168.1.157. If it returns something like Can't find testhostname.yourdomain.local: No answer your Windows Server isn't serving DNS and you need to investigate that.
Now try this, again on both systems:
ping testhostname.yourdomain.local

(It won't stop by itself on the Ubuntu system; you'll have to Ctrl C to interrupt it.)
Finally try this
ping testhostname

You may find this works, or it may not. The error I would expect if there was going to be one is that testhostname cannot be found. Should this be the case the issue is that your client doesn't know the fully qualified domain name to use. The DNS Server knows testhostname.yourdomain.local but not testhostname (they're different). Where a client knows the domain it can automatically suffix it to any unqualified query, so when you ask for testhostname the question asked of the DNS Server is really testhostname.yourdomain.local. But obviously where a client does not know the domain it can't append it, so it asks the wrong question and gets no useful answer.
The solution for the Ubuntu system depends pretty much on how you configured it. Usually the domain is supplied as part of a DHCP response - along with IP address, default gateway, and DNS servers, and that's where I would start fixing the problem.
Once you've got the DNS resolution working correctly you'll find your other applications that depend on it (i.e. your nc) can also resolve names as you'd expect

That is the scenario yes, thanks for the DNS tools. On both Windows and Ubuntu nslookup returns:  "Server:  192.168.1.189\n
Address: 192.168.1.189#53\n
\n
Name: TESTHOSTNAME.yourdomain.local\n
Address: 192.168.1.157\n
So that looks kind of correct.
On Ubuntu a ping of both testhostname and testhostname.yourdomain.local fails, but on Windows it succeeds, so not sure what to make of that.

It means you've got no DNS configured at all on the Ubuntu client, or it's using some other DNS server (what does ping -c2 bbc.co.uk return?). How did you set up this client's network connectivity?

Running "nmcli dev show |grep DNS" shows that my DNS is 192.168.1.189, 75.75.75.75, and 75.75.76.76. The ping to bbc.co.uk reaches fine.

Unless you have a DNS subsystem that is domain aware (i.e. it knows that for yourdomain.local it needs to ask only the internal server) you will need to remove the two external servers

Good suggestion thanks, I removed all DNS servers but 192.168.1.189 and flushed the DNS. Still same nslookup and ping results, including being able to ping bbc.co.uk. The ping to bbc.co.uk fails if all DNS servers are removed, so I can only assume that Windows Server provides its own DNS as well. I added a video in my post showing this on a fresh Ubuntu install. Only difference in this fresh install is that ping TESTHOSTNAME.yourdomain.local now fails with: Temporary failure in name resolution

Try changing the .local suffix to something else as that top level domain is a reserved name
